# OMR/OCR on android

Tags: android, sdk, ocr

I am going to build of a counting of vote program with optical MC sheet in android platform
However, i find that there is not many SDK for OMR in android.
Is it possible for me to read answer on optical MC sheet answer in OCR?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very tough project.  OMR is based on templates where each checkmark area has to be consistent and clearly defined.  OMR is comparison of black to white threshold against blank checkmark.  For example, if there is 15% or more black pixels compared to blank 'template' checkmark, then it can be considered marked.

With mobile pictures, each picture is inconsistent in size, and lighting will affect how your binarization works, so thresholding will be very tough to standardize.

In general, on device OCR (not even talking about OMR) is weak or too expensive, even for machine text.  I would consider server-based processing for OMR.  It is not on device, but it can be fast enough to seem like it is running right on your device.

Comment: i did not find much for a android.The OMR detection sdk is like non existing.could you please help me out in finding some.

Comment: Your best bet is custom implementation.  I am not aware of any generic solutions, which is understandable due to reasons I listed above.  Contact me with specific use case and I may be able to help with something.

Comment: I do use a back-end server platform for some of my apps and form processing.  That may work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

OMR is much different from OCR, normally OMR on a form are template-based, so you may need to have a template designer, the technology may not be new or complex, but it is hard to make it accurate and robust, there are lots of omr engines on the market, the most efficient way is calling online omr api service from http://ssomr.com/eng/video.asp?#api